# How to flatten transparency without rasterization?

Tags: vector-graphics, transparency, coreldraw

I have a simple illustration in CorelDraw with overlapping simi-transparent curves with uniform fillings, and I need to export it to EPS while maintaining everything in vector form. It is perfectly possible in principle since the illustration contains no gradients, only uniform fillings. By default CorelDraw rasterizes overlapping regions when exporting as EPS. After some trial and error I was able to achieve this by exporting it to EPS from Adobe Acrobat with non-standard settings. But I would prefer to stay with CorelDraw. Is it possible in CorelDraw?